# How do you unpair a Switch controller if you do not have a right Joycon?

Tags: technical-issues, nintendo-switch

I have a Switch with eight controllers paired to it, but unfortunately I’ve lost my right Joycon. To unpair controllers so I can pair more, I need to push X on the right Joycon.

Is there any way around this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the home menu and click on the controller settings, then go to "Change Grip/Order". From here, you should be able to disconnect the left controller from the console and press both side triggers (SL and SR) to connect it as its own controller, which should let you use it normally. Not entirely sure if this will be your solution, but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Each Joy-Con has a small button that you can hold down to pair the controller with your Switch for the first time. The button is black, and is located between the SL and SR buttons.

This same button will also turn the Joy-Con off if pressed quickly. Simply press the black button on the side of your Joy-Con and it will turn off, allowing you to connect more controllers.